# Why can I assign struct with a pointer?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

Why does it even compile?

```
struct UE{
    UE(bool a = true) {  };
//  UE(){}; // if UE took no initial args and called below, gcc will complain.
};
class VA {
    protected:
            UE ue;
    public:
            VA();
};
VA::VA()
{
    ue = new UE(true); // ???why???
//  ue = new UE(); // will complain
}
```

I tried with gcc (GCC) 4.6.2.
How can I assign a struct with a pointer?

Comment: It does compile in VS2010.

Comment: @herohuyongtao The question is why. The answer is implicit conversions.

Comment: @HenkHolterman `new` returns a pointer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're hitting the fact that you didn't mark your constructor as `explicit`, and thus it can be used for implicit conversions.

`new UE(true)` returns a pointer. All pointers can be implicitly converted to `bool`, resulting in `true` if they are non-null. `UE` can be implicitly constructed from a `bool`. So in effect, the pointer returned by `new` is converted to `bool`, which is converted to `UE` using your constructor, and then the copy assignment operator of `UE` is called. Of course, the memory allocated by `new` is leaked.

The take-home message is: always mark your single-argument constructors as `explicit` unless you actually want them to be usable for implicit conversions. By "single-argument constructor," I mean one which can be called with a single argument. Either because it has one parameter, or it has more and all parameters after the first have default arguments.

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything.

Comment: I really wish gcc would generate a warning for this.  It seems like it ought to be distinguishable from "things you might want to do".   Cppcheck (1.63.1) did not catch it.  g++ 4.7.2 did not catch it.

Comment: @ColinDBennett You mean because of the `new`? Modern C++ code shoudln't contain many `new` calls anyway, so it would apply quite seldom. And with any other way to obtain a pointer, such conversion is fair game and I would be quite annoyed if I intended it and got a warning.

Comment: @Angew possibly the warning could be predicated on the implicit conversion from a *pointer type* to *bool* being passed as a function or constructor parameter.  Typically the pointer to *bool* conversion is most useful an appropriate when used as the condition to flow control statement like `if (my_ifstream) { ... }` or `while (p) { p = p->next; ... }`, but I would personally like a warning if I pass a pointer as a parameter a function argument declared as bool.

Answer (score 8):

There is an implicit conversion from any pointer to `bool`.  Hence this code is implicitly calling the single argument constructor after converting the pointer to a `bool` value

One way to fix this is to make the single parameter constructor explicit.

```
struct UE{
    explicit UE(bool a = true) {  };
};
```

This will prevent the code from compiling unless the constructor is explicitly invoked

Answer (score 1):

Any  scalar type can be converted to boolean value true or false depending on whether its value is equal to zero or not..

In this statement

```
ue = new UE(true);
```

the implicitly defined by the compiler copy assignment operator is called. As expression new UE( true ) is not equal to zero then it can be converted implicitly to boolean value true. Class UE has conversion constructor

```
UE(bool a = true);
```

that converts an object of type bool to an object of type UE.

To prevent such usage you should define the constructor as explicit

```
explicit UE(bool a = true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mark you constructor explicit this won't work:

```
explicit UE( bool a = true) {  };
```

this is because there is an implicit conversion from the pointer to a bool, we can see this is allowed from draft C++ standard section `4.12` *Boolean conversions* says (*emphasis mine*):

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, **pointer**, or pointer to member type can be **converted to a prvalue of type bool.**